# ngclass form validation to add a new class

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to check in ng-class whether if the myform.$valid then add a class?

I tried, so if the form is valid it will add the class "orange". Not sure if ng-class can do it like this or im just doing it wrong.

```
<input data-ng-disabled="vm.registerPassword != vm.registerConfirmPassword ? vm.registerPassword : disabled; registerForm.$invalid" disabled="disabled"
                            type="submit" id="submitForm" data-ng-click="vm.registerForm()" value="Register" class="btn-main orange maxw-200" ng-class="myform.$valid: 'orange'">
```

Here for the password condition:

```
data-ng-disabled="vm.registerForm.Password !== vm.registerForm.ConfirmPassword ? vm.registerForm.Password : disabled || registerForm.$invalid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possibly. See in [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element.

```
ng-class="{'orange' : myform.$valid}"
```

Comment: ah I was missing the curly brace -.- stupid mistake -.- Thanks.

Comment: @MrNew, and also you confuse order

Comment: Really? I thought its {true: 'class'} does the order matter?

Comment: @MrNew, sure, read quotation in answer. as class added 'key' from passed object

Comment: I see, so the ngClass is working okay now :).. another question my ng-disable doesn't work if I put $invalid/$valid in the button. the button should still be disable even the user put their user/pass, etc if the password is not matched.

Comment: @MrNew, i think this already another question :-) you can create ask new, and provide relevant code. from your html that you provide here, i see that you use some _disabled_ variable, and you not pass _registerForm.$invalid_ to condition

Comment: There's really nothing else in the html apart from ng-model of password and confirmpassword inputs. I removed the "disabled" input property still didn't work. Sorry I didn't get the last bit of your reply.

Comment: I think I fixed it now, instead of breaking the ng-disabled="fuc1; fuc2" it should be an or "||". Now button is disabled if the form is empty and password is not matched

Comment: @MrNew, yep , i mean this : `cond ? a : b; $valid`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a function, such as ,

```
ng-class="isValid(myform)"
```

and in your script...

```
    $scope.isValid = function (frm){          
        if(frm.$valid == true) 
             return 'Orange'
        else 
             return '';
    }
```